# What is this type of radio aerial called?

Tags: radio, terminology

I need a replacement aerial for my FM radio, but I can't seem to find the right type. I suspect that this type of aerial has a name. It's telescopic, and has a joint so that you can angle and rotate it, but the joint can also be pushed right down inside the radio.

The only picture of one I can find is in a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6m0kXWQonJU) where someone is repairing a radio:
[image: Radio aerial with joint]

You can see the long tube part on the base end of the aerial that allows the hinge to be pushed right down inside the radio when the hinge is straight.

In contrast, trying to buy a replacement aerial, the only ones I can find are this type:
[image: Telescopic radio aerial]

Perhaps I'm using the wrong search term: [Telescopic radio aerial](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=telescopic%20radio%20aerial&iax=images&ia=images).

**Questions:**

- Does my aerial have a more specific name than just "Telescopic radio aerial"?
- What search term should I use to find the type of hinged aerial that inserts fully into the radio?

Comment: That's pretty much what I'd call it: telescopic. I seem to recall that these were made in sections. So you might try adding `section` to your search, to start. But I think you are talking about something along the lines of [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/i/2251832628755441.html?gatewayAdapt=4itemAdapt)?

Answer (score 1):

As you say it is a telescopic radio antenna, but there are many variants for different mechanical setups.

You could try an image search, or using the term "fully retractable", but your best bet might be to adapt the mechanics of the mounting to allow you to use the commonly available short base versions.

A simple stainless steel tube which is the right size to cover the bottom of the standard unit, with a cross drilled hole might suffice.

Depending on the damage to your old unit, you might even be able to remove the screw on the new and old units, and transplant the extensible section of the new unit, to the base of the old unit.